# Git push upstream with dynamic branch name inside an npm script

Tags: bash, git, npm, push, upstream-branch

Is it possible to run an npm script containing a git push command with the upstream option based on the current branch ?

As an example, I would like to be able to run a command `npm run push`.
This command will do something like `git push -u origin ${current-branch}` where `$current-branch` will be replaced by the local current git branch.

I know that this is possible to achieve it by creating a script, but I would like to know if there is already something provided by npm or git to achieve this with the minimal code requirement.

Thanks for the help !

**Solution:**

Vlad274's solution works.

*Steps:*

- Add a new file `.gitconfig` on the root of your repository
- Apply the configuration with `git config --local include.path ../.gitconfig`
- You will be able to use a new git command which will push with the origin by using the default local branch name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this with a git alias, but I assume the same commands would work via npm.

In `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    branch-name = "!git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"
    pub = "!f(){ git push -u origin $(git branch-name); };f"
```